# How to find a function's definition in an installed `npm` package?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm

Let's say I have `react-hook-form` installed in my project, and I want to see how function `useForm` is defined (written).

I click on `Go To Definition` (I use VSCode), it brings me to the type definition in `useForm.d.ts`, I click on `Go To Type Definition`, obviously it still brings me to useForm.d.ts. I press `gd` in vim mode, same thing.

I was expecting that `Go To Definition` would bring me to the function signature, not the type definition.

It's unclear to me how vscode, or npm, works in this case.

How can I find the function signature? Does VSCode have a button for it, or do I need to search around in `node_modules`?

Comment: A type definition is a function signature. Do you want to see the function implementation?

Comment: @LinDu Yes that is what I meant, implementation. I thought *signature* and *implementation* are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `Go To Source Definition`.

I followed this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6209) and learned that VSCode has had this functionality from v1.67 - [Release Note](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_typescript-47-support).

Add a shortcut to it so you remember: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F12`.